# Codecov bash uploader `eval error` on `alpine:edge` docker image

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci, codecov

I'm trying to upload coverage reports to [`codecov.io`](https://codecov.io) using the [`codecov-bash`](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash) script provided by Codecov. The bash script fails to run on Gitlab CI running an `alpine:edge` docker image.

Below is the error:

```
$ /bin/bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
/bin/sh: eval: line 107: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

And here is the relevant part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yml
  after_script:
    - apk -U add git curl bash findutils
    - /bin/bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Line 107 of the script is inside the `show_help()` function, just under `This is non-exclusive, use -s "*.foo" to match specific paths.`:

```sh
show_help() {
cat << EOF

                Codecov Bash $VERSION

          Global report uploading tool for Codecov
       Documentation at https://docs.codecov.io/docs
    Contribute at https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash


    -h          Display this help and exit
    -f FILE     Target file(s) to upload

                 -f "path/to/file"     only upload this file
                                       skips searching unless provided patterns below

                 -f '!*.bar'           ignore all files at pattern *.bar
                 -f '*.foo'            include all files at pattern *.foo
                 Must use single quotes.
                 This is non-exclusive, use -s "*.foo" to match specific paths.

    -s DIR       Directory to search for coverage reports.
                 Already searches project root and artifact folders.
    -t TOKEN     Set the private repository token
                 (option) set environment variable CODECOV_TOKEN=:uuid

                 -t @/path/to/token_file
                 -t uuid

    -n NAME      Custom defined name of the upload. Visible in Codecov UI

    -e ENV       Specify environment variables to be included with this build
                 Also accepting environment variables: CODECOV_ENV=VAR,VAR2

                 -e VAR,VAR2

    -X feature   Toggle functionalities

                 -X gcov          Disable gcov
                 -X coveragepy    Disable python coverage
                 -X fix           Disable report fixing
                 -X search        Disable searching for reports
                 -X xcode         Disable xcode processing
                 -X network       Disable uploading the file network
                 -X gcovout       Disable gcov output
                 -X html          Enable coverage for HTML files
                 -X recursesubs   Enable recurse submodules in git projects when searching for source files

    -N           The commit SHA of the parent for which you are uploading coverage. If not present,
                 the parent will be determined using the API of your repository provider.
                 When using the repository provider's API, the parent is determined via finding
                 the closest ancestor to the commit.

    -R root dir  Used when not in git/hg project to identify project root directory
    -F flag      Flag the upload to group coverage metrics

                 -F unittests        This upload is only unittests
                 -F integration      This upload is only integration tests
                 -F ui,chrome        This upload is Chrome - UI tests

    -c           Move discovered coverage reports to the trash
    -Z           Exit with 1 if not successful. Default will Exit with 0

    -- xcode --
    -D           Custom Derived Data Path for Coverage.profdata and gcov processing
                 Default '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'
    -J           Specify packages to build coverage. Uploader will only build these packages.
                 This can significantly reduces time to build coverage reports.

                 -J 'MyAppName'      Will match "MyAppName" and "MyAppNameTests"
                 -J '^ExampleApp$'   Will match only "ExampleApp" not "ExampleAppTests"

    -- gcov --
    -g GLOB      Paths to ignore during gcov gathering
    -G GLOB      Paths to include during gcov gathering
    -p dir       Project root directory
                 Also used when preparing gcov
    -k prefix    Prefix filepaths to help resolve path fixing: https://github.com/codecov/support/issues/472
    -x gcovexe   gcov executable to run. Defaults to 'gcov'
    -a gcovargs  extra arguments to pass to gcov

    -- Override CI Environment Variables --
       These variables are automatically detected by popular CI providers

    -B branch    Specify the branch name
    -C sha       Specify the commit sha
    -P pr        Specify the pull request number
    -b build     Specify the build number
    -T tag       Specify the git tag

    -- Enterprise --
    -u URL       Set the target url for Enterprise customers
                 Not required when retrieving the bash uploader from your CCE
                 (option) Set environment variable CODECOV_URL=https://my-hosted-codecov.com
    -r SLUG      owner/repo slug used instead of the private repo token in Enterprise
                 (option) set environment variable CODECOV_SLUG=:owner/:repo
                 (option) set in your codecov.yml "codecov.slug"
    -S PATH      File path to your cacert.pem file used to verify ssl with Codecov Enterprise (optional)
                 (option) Set environment variable: CODECOV_CA_BUNDLE="/path/to/ca.pem"
    -U curlargs  Extra curl arguments to communicate with Codecov. e.g., -U "--proxy http://http-proxy"
    -A curlargs  Extra curl arguments to communicate with AWS.

    -- Debugging --
    -d           Don't upload, but dump upload file to stdout
    -q PATH      Write upload file to path
    -K           Remove color from the output
    -v           Verbose mode

EOF
}
```

I've tried many things to solve the issue, but I can't find a solution. On their GitHub repo, there is this issue that seems linked but the proposed solution has not worked for me: [Failing on busybox 1.26, incorrect flags passed to `find`](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash/issues/91).

You can find the full log of the job here, line 434: https://gitlab.com/gaspacchio/back-to-the-future/-/jobs/788303704

Comment: So use bash, not `sh`. `/bin/sh:` - alpine runs `sh`. While `<(...)` is a bash extension, not available with busyboxs `sh`. You may `bash -c '/bin/bash <(...)'`

Comment: I'm trying to use `bash`, as you can see in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. However, Alpine Linux seems to use `sh` anyways.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion @KamilCuk and the error just moved a line down. It's still using `/bin/sh` though.

Comment: Because you did not add trailing `'`.... It's `bash -c '/bin/bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)'` not `bash -c '/bin/bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)` - go take a coffee.

Comment: It worked. You're a genius. Why did it work though? BTW, I'm offering you a coffee @KamilCuk, you just saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)'s comment, below is the full line needed to properly upload code coverage reports to codecov:

```sh
bash -c '/bin/bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)'
```

As pointed out by KamilCuk, notice the closing `'`.

The `-c` flag is documented as such in the man pages for `bash`:

> -c string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

As of today, I don't know *why* this works. Feel free to edit this answer if you have any clues.